# multiple query execution or one query and nextRowset() to SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

in what is efficient to execute multiple queries:

this with `nextRowset()` function to move over the queries

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT 1; SELECT 2;");
$info1 = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->nextRowset();
$info2 = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

or multiple executions plan which is a lot easier to manage?

```
$info1 = $db->query("SELECT 1;")->fetchAll();
$info2 = $db->query("SELECT 2;")->fetchAll();
```

Comment: This question may see some opinion-based answers. The only way you can find out for sure is to test both code in your workload and see which one is faster and whether the difference in speed is significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance of the code is likely to be similar.

The code at the bottom, to me, is more efficient for your software design because:

- it is more readable
- it can be changed with less chance of error since each of them addresses 1 query only
- individual query and its interaction can be moved to a different function easily and can be tested individually

That's why I feel that overall efficiency (not just how fast data comes back from DB to PHP to the user, but also maintainability/refactoring of code) will be better with the code at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

"SQL injection" by a hacker is easier when you issue multiple statements at once.  So, don't do it.

If you do need it regularly, write a Stored Procedure to perform all the steps via one `CALL` statement.  That will return multiple "rowsets", so similar code will be needed.